# The womanly and courtier-like quickness and tact habitual...?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[the source](https://books.google.jo/books?id=s-OQ2yHDIMQC&pg=PA24&dq=but%20with%20the%20womanly%20and%20courtier%20like%20quickness%20and%20tact%20hapitual%20to%20her&hl=ar&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinmpvd0ebWAhVrKMAKHfX9BHwQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=but%20with%20the%20womanly%20and%20courtier%20like%20quickness%20and%20tact%20hapitual%20to%20her&f=false) WAR & PEACE: Leo Tolstoy

> But, with the womanly and courtier-like quickness and tact habitual to her, Anna ...

Could you please paraphrase what the writer tries to say here?

If womanly is an adjective, what a word does it describe?

What is the meaning of "courtier-like quickness"?

Comment: If you break the phrasing with some brackets, it might make more sense (subject to looking up individual words in a dictionary). "But, with the [womanly and courtier-like] [quickness and tact] habitual to her, Anna ... "

Comment: Ok now it can be better and understood, but i am still confused about "womanly" which I already looked up, and i shows that is an adjective, so it should be followed by a noun. Secondly, how could break the two words "court-like and quickness" apart if there is no comma or punctuation? @WeatherVane

Comment: "War And Peace" by Tolstoy, yes?  Originally written in Russian?  And I assume this is a question from the translation?   Often translators will choose unusual phrasings to try to mimic the flow of the original language.  This example is pretty clumsy English, but it probably matches well with what Tolstoy is trying to say in his native tongue.

Comment: There are four permutations in the sentence. It describes "womanly quickness" and "womanly tact" and "courtier-like quickness" and "courtier-like tact".

Comment: An adjective doesn't have to be directly followed by a noun; it can also be followed by more adjectives and then a noun, like "a womanly (*adjective*) and courtier-like (*adjective*) quickness (*noun*)"

Comment: Thank u now it can make sense @WeatherVane  but what is meaning of "courtier-like ? Because I didn't see any answer when I google it

Comment: A **courtier** is a person who is a member of the royal court.  **courtier-like quickness** means "quickness resembling that of a courtier".